# Using Mobile SIM card with an iPad Mini

Tags: ipad, sim, cellular-data

If I buy a **Wifi and Cellular iPad Mini**, could I cut down my **mobile SIM card** and use its cellular data with the iPad?

Comment: Since the iPad mini takes a nano-sim - it's not clear if you are looking for hardware to help steady your hands while cutting or if you don't know what cards are used in the device. http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&keywords=nano-sim&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Anano-sim

Answer (score 1):

A simple question but there is no simple answer.

1. You'll need to know the frequencies and protocols used by your carrier and ensure they are supported on your iPad. 3G is highly likely to be OK but it's not 100% (for exampled, much of T-Mobile's 3G network runs on a frequency that's not compatible with the current iPad/iPhone
2. As noted, you'll need to cut the card down to nano-SIM size.  If you screw it up, the SIM is toast and will need to be replaced. You'll also need an adapter if you want to put it back into the phone.
3. The iPad needs to be configured with the proper data/APN settings for your carrier.
4. Your carrier has to not care that you are doing it.  I've heard stories about carriers detecting that a phone SIM is being used in a tablet and disabling the SIM.